# Virtualizing nVidia GPU in Citrix XenServer with Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, xen, cuda, citrix

At work we've got a host machine running Citrix XenServer 6.1 and we're planning on getting an nVidia Tesla M2070Q card for it so we can run some CUDA code.

I'm wondering if anyone has ever done this setup with an Ubuntu 12.04 VM running on XenServer, and if there are any quirks to getting it working, etc.  Or if it's never been tested, is there any reason it wouldn't work?

I've heard of GPU passthrough with open-source Xen, but I've heard it's difficult to set up.  I'm wondering if it's easy to do with XenServer.

Comment: note that I'm not interested in doing anything 3d on the client machine.  This isn't about graphics, really -- it's about running CUDA code.